# Passing parsed output of sed to find (in this direction)

Tags: bash, sed, find, pipe, parameter

Well, I think you can find dozens of questions on this platform how to pipe `find` *output* to `sed`, but I haven't found anything for the reverse direction so far. What I want to do is modify my *input*, and *then* pass it to `find`.

Supposing I want to do something like the following, in order to make life easier for myself by avoiding to type in those cumbersome asterisk wildcards. (I hope it's obvious enough that the expression which follows the here-string operator `<<<` is eventually planned to get replaced by a parameter, e. g. `$1`, in a script later. The line below is merely for demonstration.)

```
$ sed 's/ /\*/g' <<< ' foo bar baz ' | find . -type f -iname -
```

That `-` at the end of this one-liner was actually *supposed* to use the output of `sed` as input for `find`; however, extending the `find` part to

```
... find -D tree . -type f -iname - ...
```

revealed that the parameter was *not* passed to `find`. Perhaps you cannot pass pre-processed input to `find` using a pipe at all?

Comment: "*foo*bar*baz" (testing something)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find` doesn't take its args from stdin, it takes them from the command line, so:

```
find . -iname "$(sed 's/ /\*/g' <<< ' foo bar baz ')"
```

That will become:

```
find . -iname "foo*bar*baz*"
```

(the quotes are necessary to stop the shell from expanding the wildcard foo*bar*baz*)

which may or may not be what you were hoping to get.  e.g. if you really wanted files beginning with either foo, bar, or baz rather than files matching the patter 'foo*bar*baz*' then you need to construct a regexp and use `-regex` or `-iregex` rather than `-iname`.  or construct a more complicated find command like `-iname 'foo*' -o -iname 'bar*' -o -iname 'baz*'`

alternatively:

```
PATTERN='foo bar baz'
PATTERN=$(echo "$PATTERN" | sed -e 's/ /*/g')
# and/or do whatever else you need to do to transform $PATTERN to be what
# you need it to be...
find . -iname "$PATTERN"
```

---

Here's the one-liner in a bash script.  it works exactly the same in the script as it does on the command-line.

```
$ cat ./test.sh
#! /bin/bash 
find . -iname "$(sed 's/ /\*/g' <<< ' foo bar baz ')"

$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas  0 Sep 26 16:53 doesntmatch
lrwxrwxrwx 1 cas cas 16 Sep 26 16:59 symlink -> xfoo-ybar-zbaz01
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cas cas 69 Sep 26 16:50 test.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas  0 Sep 26 16:50 xfoo-ybar-zbaz01
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas  0 Sep 26 16:50 xfoo-ybar-zbaz02
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas  0 Sep 26 16:50 xfoo-ybar-zbaz03

$ ./test.sh 
./xfoo-ybar-zbaz01
./xfoo-ybar-zbaz03
./xfoo-ybar-zbaz02

$ find . -iname "$(sed 's/ /\*/g' <<< ' foo bar baz ')"
./xfoo-ybar-zbaz01
./xfoo-ybar-zbaz03
./xfoo-ybar-zbaz02

$ find . -iname "*foo*bar*baz*"
./xfoo-ybar-zbaz01
./xfoo-ybar-zbaz03
./xfoo-ybar-zbaz02
```

Comment: Thanks! That first line will already do the trick for me. Whilst lots of commands do support stdin, `find` obviously doesn't. However, I assumed that it did. :) By the way, surely you meant that there is an asterisk before "foo", as well. However it got filtered out! (I suspect it's a SE bug?)
IMPORTANT: The first line will NOT work within a standalone script! Analysed it again using the `find -D tree ...` debug mode. The ' foo bar baz ' stuff will have to be replaced by double quotes " foo bar baz ". Yes, that's right: double quotes _inside_ double quotes. And that's fine.

Comment: sorry, i copy-pasted it but i didn't even notice that leading space, so i didn't include it in what i actually typed.  feel free to add it yourself :).   How are you using the `find... "$(sed...)"` line?  It worked for me just now when i put it in a one-line bash script.

Comment: No, Craig, that's what I was trying to point out: I CANNOT ADD IT. That "leading asterisk" will get automatically removed as soon as I submit my post. It _must_ be a bug. To your question: I'm using it in a one-line bash script as you do. But I don't get any search results unless I put the "foo bar baz" expression in double quotes, that's a fact. :)

Comment: i've added my test.sh script and sample output.  the find command works exactly the same in the script as it does on the command line, and they both produce the output i expect to see.  the final output shows typing the find command in without using sed to transform spaces into asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a for loop?

```
for n in $(sed 's/ /\*/g' <<< ' foo bar baz '); do find . -iname $n; done
```

Comment: Because I actually only wanted to run find _one_ time, not n times. By the way, you've got a variable mismatch in your line.

Comment: That's a good reason and I've corrected the variable, well spotted.